# Iam trying to use Html.ActionLink to generate url with queryString parameter at the end of it

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, frontend

I am trying to use `Html.ActionLink` to generate URL with query String parameter at the end of it like:

```
Controller/Action?id=5
```

But what i get is:

```
Controller/Action/5
```

Using :

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)ViewBag.Back, "Action", "Controller", new{id = Model.Id }, new { })
```

How can i pass the id parameter as "?id=" not after "/"
Thanks

Comment: What is the method signature for that controller action and what is its route definition?  It sounds like the route includes `id` as a parameter already.  Does that not work in some way?

Comment: endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                            name: "default",
                            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

Comment: public ActionResult Details(Nullable<int> id)

Comment: That explains it then.  `id` is already part of the route, and the action method has an `id` parameter.  Is this not working for you?  Why do you want to change it to a query string parameter?  To do so you'd either need to change the route or change the action method parameter name.

Comment: i dont know why it isn't working like that .. thanks man for the explanation  and ill try to make it work in both ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change action header

```
public ActionResult Details(int? detailsId)
```

and adjust  link

```
Html.ActionLink((string)ViewBag.Back, "Action", "Controller", new{detailsId = Model.Id }, new { })
```